# How to prove $\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-\sqrt[n]{n}\sim-\frac{\ln{n}}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Show that
>
> $\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-\sqrt[n]{n}\sim-\frac{\ln{n}}{n^2}$,
>
> when $n\to+\infty$

I'm learning Taylor's Formula. The given solution is:

> $\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-\sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1}}-e^{\frac{\ln{n}}{n}}$
>
> and use Taylor's Formula:
>
> $e^{\frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1}}=1+\frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1})^2+\frac{1}{6}(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1})^3+o(\frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^3})$ and
>
> $e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}=1+\frac{\ln(n)}{n}+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\ln(n)}{n})^2+\frac{1}{6}(\frac{\ln(n)}{n})^3+o(\frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^3})$,
>
> then $\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-\sqrt[n]{n}=-\frac{\ln{n}}{n^2}+o(\frac{\ln{n}}{n^2})\sim\frac{\ln n}{n^2}$

I don't understand the last step: why is it **$=-\frac{\ln{n}}{n^2}+o(\frac{\ln{n}}{n^2})$** ? And any other solutions?

Comment: Interesting problem.  Adding your thoughts will let us know what level of mathematics you are familiar with so we know how to frame answers.

Comment: Notice $\sqrt[x]{x} = e^{\frac{\log x}{x}}$. Apply IVT to $[n,n+1]$, there is a $\xi \in (n,n+1)$ such that
$$\sqrt[n+1]{n+1} - \sqrt[n]{n} = \left.\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[x]{x}\right|_{x=\xi} =\frac{1 - \log(\xi)}{\xi^2} = \frac{-\log n}{n^2} \left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)\right)$$.

Comment: oops, should be MVT, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to handle the subtraction of series for $\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$ and $\sqrt[n] {n} $ term by term in a proper manner upto 3 terms. The first term $1$ cancels out in both series. The second terms upon subtraction lead to
\begin{align}
A &= \frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}-\frac{\log n} {n} \notag\\
&= \frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}-\frac{\log n} {n+1} +\log n\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}\right) \notag\\
&= \frac{1}{n+1}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{\log n}{n(n+1)}\notag\\
&= - \frac{\log n} {n^{2}}+\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^{2}}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^{2}}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\right)+\frac{\log n} {n} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\notag\\
&= - \frac{\log n} {n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{\log n} {n^{2}(n+1)}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\notag\\
&= - \frac{\log n} {n^{2}}+o\left(\frac{\log n} {n^{2}}\right)\notag 
\end{align}
The third terms on subtraction lead to 
\begin{align}
B &= \frac{A} {2}\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}+\frac{\log n} {n} \right) \notag\\
&= o\left(\frac{\log n} {n^{2}}\right)\notag
\end{align} 
and therefore we have $$\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-\sqrt[n]{n}=-\frac{\log n} {n^{2}}+o\left(\frac{\log n} {n^{2}}\right)$$

Comment: How comes your fourth "="?

Comment: @pwd: we have $1/(n+1)=(1/n)(1+(1/n))^{-1}$ and then use binomial theorem for negative exponent. And the series for $\log(1+(1/n))$ is already well known.

Comment: @pwd: also note that the expression $-(\log n) /(n(n+1))$ is as the sum of first and last terms in the expression given after fourth "=".

Comment: OK, I understand, thanks!